# DynamoDB with NodeJS - Get list of elements with ID not equal first query result

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm currently learning DynamoDB with NodeJS. I'm doing a function having as parameter 'userId'.

I will query dynamoDB and get this an user using the param 'userId', this works.

This is my query that gets an user :

```
let params = {
    TableName: 'user',
    KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :userId",
    ExpressionAttributeNames:{
        "#id": "id"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":userId": userId
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({
            success: false,
            message: err.message
        });
    } else {
        const {Items} = data;
        if (Items.length === 0) {
            res.send(null)
        }
        else res.send(Items);
    }
});
```

This is the query result when an user has been found :

```
[{
    "firstname": "test",
    "lastname": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "id": "1750",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "habitsList": [
        {
           id: 10
        },
        {
           id: 12
        }
    ]
}]
```

So, after dynamo has found the user, I want it to get every habits which ID do not equals to "10" and "12"

Can I do this with some changes on the query/params or do I absolutely have to do another query passing the list of IDS as params ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question correctly, that means you want the user object but the habit is filtered to not id = 10 or 12. If that's the case I think it would be easier to filter the habit after the query.

```
for(var i = 0; i < Items.length; i++){
    var filteredHabits = Items[i].habitsList.filter(h => h.id !== 10 && h.id !== 12);
    var Items[i].habitsList = filteredHabits; //this will replace the current habitList to filteredHabit
}
```